# Moment.js decimals into time format

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to format a decimal like 1.25 into a format as  follows.

I am working with FullCalendar.

What I am trying to do is remove events from the calendar, but place them back into the external events queue with proper `data-duration` attribute.

```
1 -> 01:00
1.25 -> 01:15
1.5 -> 01:30
1.75 -> 01:45
```

etc.

I will always only be working in 15 minute intervals.

Is this possible with moment.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that momentjs would be an overkill for this simple purpose.
You may want to use vanilla JS to get decimals formatted in that fashion

```
function parse(num) {
    return ('0' + Math.floor(num) % 24).slice(-2) + ':' + ((num % 1)*60 + '0').slice(0, 2);
}

parse(24.5) -> '00:30'
parse(1.25) -> '01:15'
parse(1.5) -> '01:30'
parse(1.75) -> '01:45'
```

---

Some explanation:

> ! **`Math.floor(num) % 24`** - get amount of hours
>
> ! **`'0'`**`+ Math.floor(num) % 24` - coerce number to string with leading nil
>
> ! `('0' + Math.floor(num) % 24)`**`.slice(-2)`** - get last two chars in string
>
> ! **`(num % 1)`** - get minutes as part of decimal fraction
>
> ! `(num % 1)`**`* 60 + '0'`** - coerce to minutes with trailing nil
>
> ! `(num % 1)*60 + '0')`**`.slice(0, 2)`** - get first two chars in string;

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Moment.js was already being loaded on the page, so I thought there might be a function it it's library - but this works!

Comment: I would not let this through if I saw this without unit tests in a code review... and if there were unit tests I'd still berate them for wasting time on this unless we're in some crazy environment were loading any libraries is out of questions...

Comment: Well, in general I agree that self-written snippets _almost_ always are worser than libs with all their well-tested, edge case aware solutions. Nevertheless I would think twice before importing bloated combine (like momentjs) just for some primitive transformations. Especially when it comes to browser environment. So I'd say "know your limitations and import wisely".